# Modify Sitecore form default submit action

Tags: sitecore-forms, mvc-forms

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, I created Sitecore form with submit button, I want to disable the button after certain amount of submission attempts, the logic conditions won't work, how can I modify the default submit action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your custom sumbit action:

[image]

or *(if you want to override logic of default submit action)* change `Model Type` of `Save Data` action (not recommended):

[image]

You custom submit action should look similar to:

```
public class CustomSubmitAction : SaveData // or SubmitActionBase<string>
{
    private readonly string SessionAttemptsCountKey = "CustomSubmitActionAttemptsCountKey";
    private readonly int SessionAttemptsCount = 5;
    public CustomSubmitAction(ISubmitActionData submitActionData) : base(submitActionData)
    {

    }

    protected override bool TryParse(string value, out string target)
    {
        target = string.Empty;
        return true;
    }

    protected override bool Execute(string data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
    {
        var currentAttemptsCount = 0;
        var analyticsTracker = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IAnalyticsTrackerResolver)) as IAnalyticsTrackerResolver;
        {
            if (analyticsTracker.CurrentPage.Session.CustomData.ContainsKey(SessionAttemptsCountKey))
            {
                int.TryParse(analyticsTracker.CurrentPage.Session.CustomData[SessionAttemptsCountKey] as string, out currentAttemptsCount);
                analyticsTracker.CurrentPage.Session.CustomData.Remove(SessionAttemptsCountKey);
            }
        }

        var success =  base.SavePostedData(formSubmitContext.FormId, formSubmitContext.SessionId, formSubmitContext.Fields);
        if (!success)
        {
            currentAttemptsCount++;
            analyticsTracker.CurrentPage.Session.CustomData.Add(SessionAttemptsCountKey, currentAttemptsCount);
        }

        return success;
    }
}
```

And in form constructor you can remove default `Save Data` submit action and add your custom (if you do not override default `Save Data` action):

[image]

To disable a submit button you can edit default button rendering in `Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates\Button.cshtml` like:

```
@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Constants
@model Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields.ButtonViewModel

@{
    var cssClass = Model.CssClass;
    if (Model.NavigationStep < 0)
    {
        var classes = Model.CssClass.Split(' ');
        if (!classes.Contains("cancel", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CssClass))
            {
                cssClass += " ";
            }

            cssClass += "cancel";
        }
    }
    
    // add this code snipped to add "disables" attribute
    var sessionAttemptsCountKey = "CustomSubmitActionAttemptsCountKey";
    var sessionAttemptsCount = 5;
    var currentAttemptsCount = 0;
    var disabled = "";
    if (Tracker.Current.Session.CustomData.ContainsKey(SessionVisitorCountryTag))
    {
        int.TryParse(Tracker.Current.Session.CustomData.CustomData[SessionAttemptsCountKey] as string, out currentAttemptsCount);
        if(currentAttemptsCount>=sessionAttemptsCount)
        {
            disabled = "disabled='disabled'";
        }
    }
}

// add @disabled to input render
<input value="@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.Title)" type="submit" class="@cssClass" @disabled name="@Html.Name(Model.ItemId)" data-sc-field-key="@Model.ConditionSettings.FieldKey" />
@Html.Hidden(AttributeNames.NavigationButtons, Model.ItemId)
@Html.Hidden(Model.ItemId, Model.NavigationStep)
```

**OR (recommended)**

You can create your own custom submit button:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class CustomSubmitButton : ButtonViewModel
    {
        // implement additional logic if needed
    }
```

Create new field type:
[image]

and create `CustomSubmitButton.cshtml` with code that I shared above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help